# Are questions related to issues with the user interface in Photoshop on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Photoshop is constantly moving the window application on macOS when the menu bar overlaps it. The menu bar is set to be hidden automatically. This is a question about the Photoshop user interface and preferences, but also it could be something related to the system preferences, although I'd prefer not to have the menubar set to be always visible for the whole system.

Is there a reason why this sort of question would be off topic on the [main Ask Different site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have almost 100 questions about [adobe-photoshop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop), so the program is definitely on-topic here (well, unless you'd ask about the Windows version of course).

I'd say that our sister sites [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) and [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) are better suited if you have a question about how to use the various toolsets available in the program, but this sounds like an Ask Different question to me. A screen capture would be helpful to get a good answer.